# RMI UnknownHostException

Tags: java, web, ip, rmi

I am having trouble with a Java RMI system that I am building. I keep getting an UnknownHostException when I try to connect. For host names, I've tried my IPv4 address, IPv6 address, "localhost", some other things, and more. I also tried typing in random words to see if there was a difference. There wasn't; I got exactly the same error.
Here's some code:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, WindowListener
{
public static GUI Global;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Global = new GUI();
    //Debugging
    System.out.println(Global.Client.getServerMessage());
}


public ClientIO()
{
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:./bin/settings.policy");
    /*if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
    {
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    }*/     
    System.out.println("Enter the Server IP adress (The IP adress of the machine that the server is running on)");
    try 
    {
        ClientIO.URL = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*try {
        URL = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
}

public String getServerMessage()
{
    String szRemoteAdress = URL+"/"+WebConstants.SERVICE_NAME;
    try 
    {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(szRemoteAdress);
        EotGRemote stub = (EotGRemote) registry.lookup("EotGRemote");
        String response = stub.getTextyness();
        System.out.println("response: " + response);
    }
    catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

public class GlobalNetIO implements Runnable
{
public static GlobalNetIO IO;
ServerSocket m_MainServerSocket;
ArrayList<Socket> m_Sockets;
ArrayList<UserNetIO> m_UserInterfaces;

public GlobalNetIO()
{
    makeRMI();
    try 
    {
        m_MainServerSocket = new ServerSocket(1111);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Define an ArrayList of the Socket
    m_Sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();
}

public void makeRMI()
{
    //I don't know what this means; I'm just going to accept it
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy","file:./bin/settings.policy");
    //Might as well...
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", "./");
    /*if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
        System.setSecurityManager ( new RMISecurityManager() );*/
    try
    {
        EotGRemote IO2 = new EotGRemoteIO();
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        registry.bind(WebConstants.SERVICE_NAME, IO2);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public interface EotGRemote extends Remote 
{
public String getTextyness() throws RemoteException;
}

package com.eotg.WebInterface;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import com.eotg.WebUtils.*;

public class EotGRemoteIO extends UnicastRemoteObject implements EotGRemote 
{
protected EotGRemoteIO() throws RemoteException 
{
}

@Override
public String getTextyness() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "It worked!";
}
}
```

And here's the error message:

```
java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: foo bar/Eo Nova; nested exception is: 
    java.net.UnknownHostException: foo bar/Eo Nova
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.eotg.Client.ClientIO.getServerMessage(ClientIO.java:57)
    at com.eotg.Client.GUI.main(GUI.java:34)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: foo bar/Eo Nova
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Please add the **exact** error message with Call Trace to your post.

Answer (score 1):

The `LocateRegistry.getRegistry` method takes a plain hostname, but you're passing it a URL. There is a two-arg form that takes a hostname and a port number as well.

If you want to use a URL for locating the RMI service, use `java.rmi.Naming.lookup()`.

Comment: I'm not using a URL; that's just the name of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

"foo bar/Eo Nova" is not a valid hostname.

```
String szRemoteAdress = URL+"/"+WebConstants.SERVICE_NAME;
```

Here you are appending `"/"+WebConstants.SERVICE_NAME` to the hostname.

```
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(szRemoteAdress);
```

Here you are specifying, not a hostname, but the composite string you just built. Just use the hostname here.

```
    EotGRemote stub = (EotGRemote) registry.lookup("EotGRemote");
```

Here you are looking up "EotGRemote". Where does `WebConstants.SERVICE_NAME` come into it?

This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I know. But the error is identical whatever I type into the keyboard, so I just used 'foo bar' as an example. I can type my IP adress, 'localhost', the name of my machine, whatever. I still get the same error.

Comment: It would be more to the point to have used an example that meant something to other people, don't you think? The problem is the "/Eo Nova" part.

Comment: Oh. So sorry! WebContants.SERVICE_NAME is a readonly string that reads "Eo Nova". Should have clarified that.

Comment: No, wait, you were right, I was wrong, I'm an idiot, it works now, yay!

Comment: I tried, but it won't let me. I need more reputation, it says.